# Android : Make buttons appear at bottom of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, audio-recording, android-audiorecord

I have a class to record audio notes i wish to implement this into an existing activity, however the record and play buttons in this instance, end up at the top of the screen and mess things up.

Where and how can I specify the display properties of the button's using the following code...

**JAVA** - AudioRecordTest.java

```
public class AudioRecordTest extends Activity
{
private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest";
private static String mFileName = null;

private RecordButton mRecordButton = null;
private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;

private PlayButton   mPlayButton = null;
private MediaPlayer   mPlayer = null;

private void onRecord(boolean start) {
    if (start) {
        startRecording();
    } else {
        stopRecording();
    }
}

private void onPlay(boolean start) {
    if (start) {
        startPlaying();
    } else {
        stopPlaying();
    }
}

private void startPlaying() {
    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
        mPlayer.prepare();
        mPlayer.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }
}

private void stopPlaying() {
    mPlayer.release();
    mPlayer = null;
}

private void startRecording() {
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }

    mRecorder.start();
}

private void stopRecording() {
    mRecorder.stop();
    mRecorder.release();
    mRecorder = null;
}

class RecordButton extends Button {
    boolean mStartRecording = true;

    OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onRecord(mStartRecording);
            if (mStartRecording) {
                setText("Stop recording");
            } else {
                setText("Start recording");
            }
            mStartRecording = !mStartRecording;
        }
    };

    public RecordButton(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
        setText("Start recording");
        setOnClickListener(clicker);
    }
}

class PlayButton extends Button {
    boolean mStartPlaying = true;

    OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onPlay(mStartPlaying);
            if (mStartPlaying) {
                setText("Stop playing");
            } else {
                setText("Start playing");
            }
            mStartPlaying = !mStartPlaying;
        }
    };

    public PlayButton(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
        setText("Start playing");
        setOnClickListener(clicker);
    }
}

public AudioRecordTest() {
    mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    mRecordButton = new RecordButton(this);
    mPlayButton = new PlayButton(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio_record_test);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mRecorder != null) {
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
    }

    if (mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }
}
}
```

**XML** - activity_audio_record_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
 >
<ScrollView 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
>

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:orientation="vertical">
 >
<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Inspection ID" />

<EditText
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/txtName"
android:inputType="number"
android:maxLength="5"
android:digits="0123456789"
android:singleLine="true"
/>

<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Text1" />

<EditText
  android:id="@+id/txt1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:autoText="false"
  android:gravity="top|left"
  android:lines="4"
  android:maxLines="4"
  android:minLines="4"
  android:scrollbars="vertical"
  android:singleLine="false"
  android:width="0dip" />

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Project Ref"

/>
<EditText
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/txtAge"
android:inputType="number"
android:maxLength="5"
android:digits="0123456789"
android:singleLine="true"
/>
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Drop Down"
/>

<Spinner
  android:id="@+id/spinDept"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
  android:id="@+id/btnPhotoCamera"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
  android:text="Take Image with Camera" />

<Button
  android:id="@+id/btnPhotoGallery"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
  android:text="Get Image from Gallery" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblDisplayImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="below_this_text_image_will_be_displayed"
        android:textSize="13dp" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblDisplayImage"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="bottom" >
        <!--
             <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgDisplayImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:contentDescription="area_where_image_is_to_be_displayed" />
        <!-- </ScrollView> -->
    </RelativeLayout>

<------------------- RECORD AND PLAY BUTTONS TO GO HERE ------------->

  <Button
  android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:onClick="btnAddEmp_Click"
  android:text="Save Inspection" />

  <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnPhotoGallery"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="Reset/Clear Form Data" />

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/txtEmps"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Number of Inspections on Device " />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks,

henry

Comment: the positioning of any widgets is normally done within the layout-files(xml).  can you show whats inside the xml-file where your buttons are?

Comment: @bofredo the `Button`s are created programmatically

Comment: ordinaratly, I would launch an intent using a button and an `onClick` however in this case, the buttons appear "MAGICALLY" from what i believe to be `@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {...`

Comment: I have posted an answer that can show you how to do it in xml. There's no need here to do them in Java. They don't appear "MAGICALLY". They are being created programmatically

Comment: CREATE A LAYOUT PARAMETER WITH GRAVITY SET TO BOTTOM AND IN ADDVIEW PASS THAT PARAMETER

Answer (score 1):

If you really need them created dynamically then we can help with that. However, it looks like you are creating them unconditionally every time in `onCreate()` so it would be a lot easier to put them in your xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".AudioRecordTest" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/btnLL"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layuout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">    <!-- This property will put them at the bottom of the screen -->
       <Button
          android:id="@+id/recBtn"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layuout_height="wrap_content"
          />
       <Button
          android:id="@+id/playBtn"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layuout_height="wrap_content"
          />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Remove your `Button` and `LinearLayout` creation from `onCreate()` and change

```
setContentView(ll);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio_record_test);
```

you can now set your `onClick`s in one of 3 different ways. One way is to just do it when you initialize your `Button` with `buttonName.setOnClickListener( new OnclickListener(){...`. Another way, and easier and cleaner sometimes IMO, is to do it in xml by adding `android:onClick="someFunction"` to your `Button` then in your Java have a function

```
public void someFunction(View v)
{
    // place code to run here when that button was clicked
}
```

do the same with the other. You can also use the same function for them and switch on the button `id`. I can link to an example if you want

Comment: haha I had just put usually I had had them in my XML, but in the code I copied they came from `@Override public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {...` so if I add to XML, presumably, then I would need to remove this foremost mentioned onCreate?

Comment: Remove the `Button` and `LinearLayout` references from `onCreate()`. And see the update to my answer.

Comment: sort of... buttons are ok,  I tweeked, however functionally they do nothing... what are my onclicks? is this because I am missing `<LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/btnLL"` ?

Comment: See my update. You just set them as you normally would which could be one of several different ways.

Comment: can we look at this a different way.. I want to possition them above this button `<Button
      android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:onClick="btnAddEmp_Click"
      android:text="Save Inspection" />`

Comment: So you want btnAdd at the bottom of the screen and the others directly above that?

Comment: second from the bottom... the save button will appear at the bottom. the record and play buttons just above this...

Comment: ideally programatically, as I like the modifying of play to pause, and record to stop recording etc when using the buttons... Crazy change of direction i know haha

Comment: That's a lot to look at but basically use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` for whichever you want at the bottom. Then use `android:layout_above="@id/idOfViewYouWantBelowThis"` for the others

Comment: It will be too messy programmatically. Just put the `Buttons` in the same place like "play/pause" and use `btnName.setVisibility=(View.VISBLE)` and `(View.GONE)` to replace the `Buttons` when you want to

Comment: Sorry, `btnName.setVisibility(View.VISBLE)`. That's Java

Comment: `android:layuout_height="wrap_content"` should be `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`